# Is it possible to italicize "et al." in a CSL style?

Tags: xml, citations, csl

I'm trying to create a CSL style to automate my citations for research papers (and lab reports). My department has decided that other places make citations too complicated, so they have created their own style that students have to use. One of the requirements for this style is that "et al." must be italicized. However, I can't seem to get CSL to do that. Is this at all possible? [X-posted from Academia]

Comment: Also, lol to the idea of making things _simpler_ by asking students to follow a new citation style rather than an existing standard...

Comment: The rules are much simpler and work within our other confines. For example, in a lab report we're not allowed to cite anything other than published, peer-reviewed scientific articles. In-line citations take the form "(Doe et al. 2000)" and referenced literature entries take the form "Doe, J., Smith, S., and Brown, G. 2000. Comparative analysis of comparative analyses. Journal 45(60):100-130". It makes sure that students give enough information to verify the source without spending too much time fiddling with rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is, see http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#et-al.
You can explicitly list `et-al` as a sub-element of `names` and then apply styling to it, such as

```
<names variable="author">
  <name and="text"/>
  <et-al font-style="italic"/>
</names>
```

Comment: Thank you! (Sorry it took so long to get back to you.)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to italicize all Latin words? It occurs to me that this would be difficult to program.

Comment: Not automatically, but while not part of the CSL standard, most CSL processors recognize wrapping parts of titles in html tags for italics, i.e. `<i>homo sapiens</i>`